# Ionic 5 Alert buttons are all capital

Tags: ionic-framework, button, ionic5

I am using Ionic 5 and like all Ionic frameworks in `md` mode all button text is all capital. So I have maintained the following in `global.scss` file.

```
ion-button{
        text-transform:none!important;
}
```

It's working for normal buttons but the **Alert buttons are still all capital**. How can I set **global parameters for the Alert button**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [Ionic Alert](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert) buttons use `.alert-button` or `.alert-button-inner` inside `.alert-wrapper` class.

```
   .alert-wrapper {
    .alert-button {
        color: red;
        text-transform: none;
     }
   }
```

**global.scss**

[image]